# When reloading the page in Next.js, there is a delay in applying Antd CSS

Tags: next.js, antd, css-in-js

The issue I am facing is that when I reload the page in Next.js while using Antd CSS, there is a delay in applying the CSS styles. In other words, the styles are not being applied immediately upon reloading the page, which is causing some visual inconsistencies. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the Antd CSS is applied without any delay?

I know it's because of SSR that CSS is not applied while JS is being read, but I couldn't solve it.

**version**

- next.js: 12
- antd: 5

**gif description**

- [click to see the image description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KN3D.gif)

I tried following this repo, but it didn't work

https://github.com/ant-design/create-next-app-antd/blob/main/pages/_document.tsx

Comment: Are you importing your antd css in _app.jsx/_app.tsx?

Comment: the original antd/dist/antd.css has been abandoned. in antd 5
https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#technology-adjustment

Comment: I solved it by looking at this repository: https://github.com/ant-design/create-next-app-antd.

Comment: @moon Faced the same problem but could not solve it by looking at the repository. Can you write your solution?

Comment: https://github.com/TEAM-TAB-SPACE/tabspace-front/commit/9ea944c4b4ad5073bd47381fce146c98df7db3d1

Comment: @Evgenii I'm sorry for seeing your comment just now. The link you provided is my fix commit for this issue. It may be late, but I hope my code can be helpful to you.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue by looking at the repo @moon linked to.

If you are using next 13 and above and you are using the app dir, do this.

**1.) Create a Component called `AntdStyledComponentsRegistry` and add this
code.**

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { StyleProvider, createCache, extractStyle } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';

export default function AntdStyledComponentsRegistry({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [cache] = React.useState(() => createCache()); // gets antd cached styles

    // innsert cache style on the server
    useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
        <style id="antd" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: extractStyle(cache, true) }}></style>
    ));

    return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>;
}
```

**2.) Now wrapp your app dir root layout with `AntdStyledComponentsRegistry` Component**

```
// ...other imports
import AntdStyledComponentsRegistry from "@/where-you-kept-the-file/AntdStyleRegistry";


export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}


export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={gliroyFont.className}>
        <AntdStyledComponentsRegistry>
              {children}
        </AntdStyledComponentsRegistry>

      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

For More Details and info click and look through this github [Repo](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-examples/tree/main/examples/with-nextjs-app-router-inline-style)

Comment: this really work, thanks!

Comment: 'use client' in the root component will kill the SSR?

Comment: @Undefitied Yes, it converts the component and all its child components from server component to client components hence disabling SSR