# Antd styles are now overriding the custom classes CSS by using useServerInsertedHTML from next.navigation

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, antd, server-side-rendering

I was first facing a problem that my antd styles were taking a delay of 1 to 2 seconds to load due to which my page was not rendering correctly for the first 2 seconds, But after taking guidance from this answer
[Slow Antd Styles loading problem solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76107147/when-reloading-the-page-in-next-js-there-is-a-delay-in-applying-antd-css)

I was able to solve this problem,
but now the other problem I am facing is that the **":where"** styles of andt are now overriding my custom classes CSS, I tried every solution but I am stuck at this, I don't want to use **!important** for this problem's solution,

now my page renders perfectly but my styles are overridden

[image: overriden Button Example]

this is just one example a lot of part of my site is now like this

[image: Button Code]

you can see **:where** of antd is now overriding my custom styles of **buttonStyle** as it is appearing before my class styles

this is my AntdStyledComponentsRegistry component

```
'use client';

import React from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { StyleProvider, createCache, extractStyle } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';

export default function AntdStyledComponentsRegistry({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const [cache] = React.useState(() => createCache()); // gets antd cached styles

    // innsert cache style on the server
    useServerInsertedHTML(() => (
        <style id="antd" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: extractStyle(cache, true) }}></style>
    ));

    return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>;
}
```

and this is my main layout.js file

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { NavBar } from '../../../components';
import AntdStyledComponentsRegistry from "../../utils/AntdStyledComponentsRegistry"
import './dashboardStyle.scss';

const SideBar = dynamic(() => import('../../../components/SideBar'), { ssr: false })

export default function Layout({ children }) {

    return (
        <AntdStyledComponentsRegistry>
            <section>
                <div className="dashboard">
                    <NavBar />
                    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                        <div className="layout-side-bar">
                            <>
                                <SideBar />
                            </>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                            <div className="lower-layout">
                                <div className="layout-side-body">{children}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </AntdStyledComponentsRegistry>
    );
}
```

Comment: _"is now overriding my custom styles of buttonStyle as it is appearing before my class styles"_ - it's not because of the order, but because of [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). So increase the specificity of your own rules then, if you don't want to have to use !important.

Comment: @CBroe, it's not about just specificity, I have to do this for all of my styles of every component then, actually, if I don't use **AntdStyledComponentsRegistry** tag as a parent, then all the styling of my entire app is just perfect but that problem remains that styles take one to two seconds to load completely, actually AntdStyledComponentsRegistry component has increased the priority of antd styles than my own styles

Answer (score 0):

You can change antd component styles in many different ways:

You can change it by setting [token](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme) config:

OBS: You can find a list of all props you can change on every component [here](https://ant.design/theme-editor)

```
<ConfigProvider
    theme={{
      token: {
        // primary seed Token
        colorPrimary: '#00b96b',
        borderRadius: 2,

        // Alias Token
        colorBgContainer: '#f6ffed',
        Button: {
          primaryShadow: '0 2px 0 rgb(255, 0, 0)',
          colorPrimary: 'red',
          ... etc...
        } 
      },
    }}
  >
    <Button type="primary">Primary</Button>
  </ConfigProvider>
```

You can also use each component `style` prop:

```
<Button type="primary"
  style={{
    color: 'red'
  }}
>
  Primary Button
</Button>
```

This is my favorite way: Use a custom `js/ts` file to handle components styles (so you can keep styles separated by each page/component):

```
// 
// component file
//
import Styles from 'path/to/styles.js|ts'

...

function MyComponent() {
  const S = Styles()

...

  return (
    <Button type="primary"
      style={ S.Button }
    >
      Primary Button
    </Button>
  )
}

//
// styles.ts file
//
import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

// types
type StylesType = {
  Button: CSSProperties
  OtherComponent: CSSProperties
}

function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  const Button: CSSProperties = {
     color: theme.colorError
  }

  const OtherComponent: CSSProperties = {
    ....
  }

  return {
    Button,
    OtherComponent
  }
}

export default Styles
```

But if you still want to use `css` so the easest way to solve this overriding is to use `!important` but you can also try what `@CBroe` said:

> increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of your own rules

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: thanks for the help brother but this way, I have to do this for all of my classes and their styles, the main problem is that everything was working perfectly but after using AntdStyledComponentsRegistry tag, the slow CSS loading problem is solved but my styles priority has been decreased, I can't fix this for every of my file as that would can take a lot of time